# Which protocol is Apache Zeppelin using to connect to Apache Spark? (iPython/ZeroMQ)?

Tags: apache-spark, ipython, zeromq, apache-zeppelin, akka-zeromq

I'm wondring which protocol Apache Zeppelin is using to connect to Apache Spark?

Is it also the iPython Protocol on ZeroMQ?

Thanks a lot!

best regards

Romeo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Spark Interpreter** for Apache Zeppelin (incubating) actually uses neither of them.

It just hosts Spark Driver inside spark interpreter process and submits a job per paragraph though [SparkIMain](https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin/blob/master/spark/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/spark/SparkInterpreter.java#L621), in the same way as spark-shell does.

I believe an internal low-level communication between Driver and Master is based on Akka but is a Spark-specific implementation detail.

Comment: Just found this link here, where somebody created a Scala Library for hiding the Akka complexity, also has a nice architecture diagram: http://www.spark.tc/overview-of-the-spark-kernel-client-library/